# How to combine data from 2 repositories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, repository, repository-pattern, repository-design

I have a question concerning combine datas from 2 repositorys in asp / mvc.

I have 2 repositories, for example, UserRepo and InvoiceRepo.

Now I want to create a query that contains user data and invoice data
(for example: All users with address and data from the last invoice).

What is best way for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have to do it with one call?

```
var users = userRepos.GetUsers();
var lastInvoices = invoiceRepos.GetLastInvoiceForAllUsers();
var usersWithInvoices = (from x in users
                         select new UserWithInvoice(x, lastInvoices.First(inv => inv.userId = x.Id);
```

That will be two `SELECT`s and must be easier to understand.

Comment: Please note, that this may be loading whole tables from db, depending on implementation. Will be tricky if paging is required (not mentioned in question, though)

Comment: If paging is required simply pass a `int[] userId` to the `GetLastInvoiceForUsers`

Answer (score 1):

You can extend an existing repository (probably `InvoiceRepo`) with a method that performs a join and return all the data you need.

`InvoiceRepo.GetUserInvoices(userId)` sounds like a sensible option.

This is a common problem with repository pattern - finding a proper repo for your method.